# Comparing two acceleration profiles

Tags: frequency-spectrum, reference-request

#### Background

I am analyzing robot manipulator trajectories generated by different methods.

One quality that I am interested in is how "smooth" the tool point moves along those trajectories. Now, let's say I have two trajectories of the same robot executing the same tasks, but the trajectories have been generated by different generators. Then I sample tool accelerations along those trajectories and look at frequency components of those accelerations (generated via discrete Fourier transform).

| Generator 1 | Generator 2 |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Frequency components of tool accelerations along a trajectory generated by method 1] | [image: Frequency components of tool accelerations along a trajectory generated by method 1] |

From the pictures, Generator 2 seems to generate trajectories that have "flatter"/"less" high-frequency components of tool accelerations, which is desirable.

#### Question

- Are there any measures that I can use to quantitatively say that trajectories from one generator is "better" than the other in the sense that they have "less" high-frequency components? I would appreciate any pointers to related keywords, topics, etc.

The idea I have right now is that maybe I can look at the energy of these signals then say something like, the energy of signal 1 corresponding to all frequencies higher than $f$ is $E_1$; similarly, the energy of signal 2 is $E_2$; then I compare $E_1$ and $E_2$. However, I am not certain if this makes any sense, physically or mathematically.

Answer (score 0):

@Petch Puttichai: This sounds like an interesting problem. You wrote, "Generator 2 seems to generate trajectories that have "flatter"/"less" high-frequency components". Looking at your spectral plots it looks to me like the Generator 2 spectra actually contain more high frequency spectral components than the Generator 1 spectra. (It's hard to say because the x-y axes labels in your plots are unreadable.)

I suggest you determine (somehow) what would be the spectrum of "ideal" (perfect) trajectory acceleration, and then compare your Gen# 1 and Gen# 2 spectra to that ideal spectra. That is, determine which of the Gen# 1 and Gen# 2 spectra most closely matches the idea spectra.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I edited the post, hopefully the pics are clearer now. Currently I still don’t have any idea yet how the “ideal” acceleration spectrum should look like, let alone being obtainable. I thought that maybe without the ideal reference, I would still be able to at least say something about the generators’ relative quality.

Comment: But let’s say somehow I have the ideal acceleration spectra. How do I mathematically say that spectra A more closely matches the ideal than spectra B? What kind of measures I can use to quantify that?

Comment: Compare the "mean square error" (MSE) between spectral magnitudes A and the Ideal spectral magnitudes (producing MSE_A) with mean square error between spectral magnitudes B and the Ideal spectral magnitudes (producing MSE_B). If MSE_A is smaller than MSE_B then spectra A more closely matches the ideal spectra than does spectra B. Have a look at: byjus.com/maths/mean-squared-error